# Strang , Introduction to Linear Algebra, Clarification of Breakdown of Elimination Chapter 2

Tags: linear-algebra

I am sorry in advance if my question is very simple, I am just a beginner.

In Strang's "Introduction to Linear Algebra" in Section 2.2 page # 46 , he is explaining "Breakdown of Elimination", and he mentions, "The Column picture shows the two columns (1,3) and (-2,-6) in the same direction. All combinations of the columns lie along a line."

He again mentions the on page # 47 " The column picture is also normal (column vectors not in the same direction."

Now my question is the vectors he mentions (1,3) and (-2,-6) are in ***opposite*** direction, but on the same line. How is he saying that they are in same direction?

Second question: The rule should be that Elimination fails if the vectors are in same direction or opposite direction, am I right in this?

Thanks to all who have taken time to answer.

Comment: The rule is that, in order to avoid a ''break down'' none of the columns should be written as a linear combination of the rest ones. In other words, working with column picture, each column define a $n$-dimensional vector, if another column is on the same direction then it is non independent thus your elimination may produce non zero pivots. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks darkmoor but if you look at the columns in the example (1,3) and (-2,-6) they are in oppostite direction, and he is still considering both vectors in the same direction, that is the source of my confusion.

Comment: The direction doesn’t matter. What matters is that the two vectors are colinear, i.e., one is a scalar multiple of the other, even if that scalar is negative.

Comment: Thanks, I understand it. What I am really asking is that vectors  (1,3) and (-2,-6) are in same direction and if so how? Is it some misunderstanding I have because according to me they are in opposite direction.

Comment: I sure that he really means  “colinear” in this context.